# TypeError while loading a model

Tags: python, flask, pickle

I am having an issue on flask while loading my model while building a REST API. This is the line of code that is failing:

```
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","r"))
```

The resulting exception traceback message is:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your file in binary mode using:

```
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","rb"))
```

Comment: Tried that, it ABORTS!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Seems fine to me.

Comment: When I run it on the terminal, it says 'abort'